# apt-get update not working

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

I'm having problems updating `apt`.

When run `apt-get update`

```
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Hit http://ftp.bg.debian.org testing InRelease
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release          
Hit http://ftp.bg.debian.org testing/main Sources/DiffIndex 
Hit http://ftp.bg.debian.org testing/contrib Sources/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.bg.debian.org testing/non-free Sources/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.bg.debian.org testing/main armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.bg.debian.org testing/contrib armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.bg.debian.org testing/non-free armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.bg.debian.org testing/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.bg.debian.org testing/contrib i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.bg.debian.org testing/non-free i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.bg.debian.org testing/contrib Translation-en/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.bg.debian.org testing/main Translation-en/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.bg.debian.org testing/non-free Translation-en/DiffIndex
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release       Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong     sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have no idea where this `dl.google.com` comes from since my `source.list` is:

```
deb http://ftp.bg.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.bg.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you on raspberry pi?

Comment: No, Debian x86.
Linux debian 3.11.6-031106-generic #201310181453 SMP Fri Oct 18 19:02:28 UTC 2013 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: Then just ignore it, it's the arm packages that are failing

Comment: check /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ for files mentioning dl.google.com.

Comment: Not really a programming question, though. This belongs on Superuser or Unix&Linux ...

Answer (score 0):

I really think that the problem you are facing is caused from some wrong entries on the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`  folder. Check this folder and delete everything related with `dl.google.com` then retry, and everything should work properly. You probably have installed google-chrome via google's .deb package and those entries where auto-added on that folder.

**NOTE** : After doing that your google-chrome will recieve no updates, so for a new version you will have to purge it with `dpkg` and then redownload and reinstall it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

```
Go to Applications -> 'ubuntu software center'
Click on Edit -> Software Sources
Click on 'Other software' tab
Uncheck the line containing 'http://dl.google.com/linux'
Press Close
Exit 'ubuntu software center'
Retry apt-get update on command-line
```